# How does sound propagate up a tall building?

Tags: waves

I live in a flat in a 22-storey tall building. It is a common observation that loud people at level 1 can still be audibly heard even at this height.

Could someone suggest a reason for this counter-intuitive observation? Doesn't sound intensity decrease linearly with the square of the distance from the source? Is it possible that the building is acting as a surface for the sound to bounce and echo off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the echo idea (with a bit of finesse) is the best bet. As the original sound propagates as a sphere, as you suggested, every place it touches becomes a transmission point for another spherical wave front; this is basically Huygens Principle. The sound bounces back and forth among all the surfaces in the area creating echos ad infinitum - these are called multiples.  Fresnel explained how interference of these waves could produce a coherent signal at another location.  Because there are so many multiples, constructive interference compensates for some of the spherical energy loss - thus you can still hear it on your balcany.

Sound and light are sufficiently analogous at this level for the principles to work for both.

This article has some great illustrations and more information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens-Fresnel_principle

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 spontaneous guesses:
1. Echo from another building
2. Echo within the hallways of your building
3. Sound waves travelling through the steel structure of your building. This source (http://functionspace.com/topic/3372/Damping-of-Sound-Waves-in-an-Elastic-Medium) suggests that damping is less the more elastic the medium is.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I should have said that  I have assumed that you can hear noise on the outside balcony.
 END EDIT

Perhaps not so much echo off, more as if the sound is  simply channelled up the side of the building by a breeze that is horizontal at ground level and then simply has no where else to go but up.

You could test it yourself on slightly windy days, is your voice lifted up to that level?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is sound transmission through the structure of the building.

If a sound is being generated in a closed room, then the entire surface area of the walls, floor and ceiling can potentially act as a collector of the acoustic energy in the air. The floor may be covered in a carpet which damps the sound reaching it, but walls and ceilings are usually fairly resonant structures.

Similarly, the entire surface area of your room can potentially act as a transmitter.

The physics of this is quite similar to [tin can telephones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone) (sometimes still used as children's toys), where the two rooms function like the cans, and the steel frame of the building is like the string.